# Clone a wordpress website with same functionality, but different content

Tags: multisite, clone-site

I have got a Wordpress website and I would like to create a new one with exactly the same functions, themes/templates (apart from the color), plugins, etc. An exact clone of the current one, but with different content and name of sections.

Is there any plugin I can use or should I just copy the website, delete contents and change the name of the sections? Is there any tutorial? I can I reset all the id and the stats of the previous website?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Built in!

WordPress comes with feature for this: **»MU«** or Multisite or Network.

You can [read more about it in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

### Summed up

The most important part is a single line in your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

Then you have to decide whether you want to use sub domains or sub directories.

One thing you've to be aware off: Not all plugins can be used in MU installations. Some have functionality, that depends on stuff like the `$blog_id`, which is a separate ID for every sub installation/clone/site you run. Always check this one first (Hint: Make one subsite that you use for testing).

Comment: Thanks Kaiser, it is a good solution but I'm not a wordpress expert, it looks like the drupal multisite(which is quite good) but I don't want to touch the current working website. I need to clone it. What can I do? Thanks

Comment: Exactly what I've written above. (Make sure you read the Codex entry). It's painless. :)

Comment: This looks more like Multisite. I don't need to create a network, I would like to know if I can backup the current one, uopload it in a new ftp along with the db, delete all the contents and add new contents. Is it possible?

Comment: _"upload it in a new ftp"_ ... what's an "ftp" (aside from a way to _connect_ to a server)? If you're searching for moving your site, then search in [tag:staging], [tag:development-strategy], [tag:workflow] and [tag:production].

Comment: Yes, I will not be under the same webspace. I do not want to create a network. I want to clone the website. I've got example.com and I want to create example2.com. they are the same a part from the category names and the contents. May I copy the whole website, delete the contents and upload the new one?

Comment: Would you _please_ go and read about it in the tag archives I linked to?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Duplicator:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicator/

It seems to do what you are asking for.

Otherwise you could make a backup of all the files on your server to your computer as well as a backup of the database and do a batch replace in your favorite text editor of the old url to the new url and then change the database login credentials/wp credentials, then reupload to a new server and import the database export into the new database.

You may run into problems with characters being converted. This is explained (with a fix) here:
http://digwp.com/2011/07/clean-up-weird-characters-in-database/

Also, Widgets you have set up sometimes have problems when doing exports like this but there is another plugin to help with that, Widget Data - Setting Import/Export Plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-settings-importexport/

You should do the widget export before doing the batch replace of the old url to the new url in your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

We have just launched a new plugin that automates WordPress network site cloning beautifully. It's ease of use to power and flexibility ratio is better than other tools previously available. There's a free version available on wordpress.org and a new Pro version as well that adds a powerful set of additional features - http://neversettle.it/ns-cloner-pro/ - hopefully this helps anyone looking for a great multisite / wpmu blog cloner!